# Order tuples in list in python

Tags: python

```
lst=[('fondamenti', 4, 4), ('googlecode', 1, 1), ('stylesheet', 2, 2), ('javascript', 1, 1), ('inlinemath', 1, 1), ('operazioni', 2, 3), ('permettono', 2, 1), ('istruzioni', 4, 3), ('tantissime', 1, 1), ('parentnode', 1, 1)]
```

How can I order these tuples in a list?
They should be order by the sum of the occurrences, the result should be this:

```
lst=[(u'fondamenti', 4, 4), (u'istruzioni', 4, 3), (u'operazioni', 2, 3), (u'stylesheet', 2, 2), (u'permettono', 2, 1), (u'googlecode', 1, 1), (u'inlinemath', 1, 1), (u'javascript', 1, 1), (u'parentnode', 1, 1), (u'tantissime', 1, 1)]
```

Comment: I don't see any sets.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The OP means `tuple`, they just didn't know the terminology.

Answer (score 4):

The [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin has a `key` option for supplying a function by which to sort.  You want to sort on the sum of index 1 and 2. This also needs to be in reversed order.

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1] + x[2], reverse=True)
[('fondamenti', 4, 4),
 ('istruzioni', 4, 3),
 ('operazioni', 2, 3),
 ('stylesheet', 2, 2),
 ('permettono', 2, 1),
 ('googlecode', 1, 1),
 ('inlinemath', 1, 1),
 ('javascript', 1, 1),
 ('parentnode', 1, 1),
 ('tantissime', 1, 1)]
```

The above is in "interactive session" notation, where I show you the output without assigning to a variable. In real code you would do either of the following:

```
# Sort and return a new object in the same name.
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1] + x[2], reverse=True)
# Or, sort in-place.
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1] + x[2], reverse=True)
```

Do *either* of the above, not both.

P.S. Each of the elements is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple), not a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi "Does not work" is not helpful.  What isn't working? Did you get a result you did not want, or did it crash your computer?  I get _exactly_ the result you wanted.

Comment: this is that print me:

Comment: [('fondamenti', 4, 4), ('googlecode', 1, 1), ('stylesheet', 2, 2), ('javascript', 1, 1), ('inlinemath', 1, 1), ('operazioni', 2, 3), ('permettono', 2, 1), ('istruzioni', 4, 3), ('tantissime', 1, 1), ('parentnode', 1, 1)]

Comment: You need to reassign to a variable... let me be very clear in my update.

Comment: LOL. try: `lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1] + x[2], reverse=True)` and then print the list

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi that's a good way to do it - why do you want *another* way ?

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi You will need to get used to people demonstrating how Python functions work with the `>>> ...` notation. Rarely do people show the output being assigned to a variable, it is assumed you can do that extra step yourself.

Comment: I mean, you _could_ iterate through everything and work from there... Also we're not here to just do your homework, fyi. ;)

Comment: Well... I did show both `sorted` and `.sort`, and that is two different methods.

Comment: how i can this?

Comment: How can you do what? If you have a second question, you should ask a second question rather than adding more comments.